# Determine web application not using windows authentication

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom

I've been trying to determine if a web application is using windows authentication. I've been looking at the following but not sure if I'm checking the correct properties:

```
$webApplication = Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplicationUrl;
$webApplication.IisSettings[0]
```

This is my scenario.

I have a web application which is set up with only 'Enable Forms Based Authentication (FBA)' the provider for this is AD.

In the application I am working on, it uses windows authentication and CSOM. Without Windows Authentication I am unable to access the site etc. My workaround for this was to extend the application into the CUSTOM zone with Windows Authentication enabled. Once this is done it works without any problems.

What I would like to do is identify which web applications will need to be extended. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not you check you from central admin? it is easy

Comment: I was hoping I could automate it a bit. They could run the script and it would tell them without having to click on each web application unless there is another view?